# 240 V three phase motor with VFD maxes out at 10 Hz

Tags: motor, three-phase, vfd

I have a [Precious Plastic-style](https://bazar.preciousplastic.com/machines/extruder-pro/) plastic extruder that I built.

It's a big motor hooked up to a worm gear drive thing, that turns a big corkscrew inside of a hot pipe.

[image]

All the parts seem to be working fine except my motor seems to be too weak or something.

[image]

The motor says that it is a 230 /460 volt three phase induction motor.

I'm feeding two-phase 240 split voltage to a VFD that's supposed to convert it to three phase and also let me change the speed of the motor.

The voltage from the walls is the US-style "split voltage" I've heard it called, we are in Panama in a rainforest and all the electricity runs a bit high, but basically is two 120 V wires that add up to 240 V.

There are four wires that come out of the VFD - three phases (L1, L2, L3 and a ground).

The motor says it is 3 horsepower and 60 Hz.

It all turns on and works. It just seems like it's very weak in a strange way.

[image]

For instance, on the VFD I can rotate the knob to change the frequency or current that I'm giving it. I'm not sure exactly what the single knob is doing, only that I can see that the frequency and current do go up when I rotate the knob.

When I turn the knob changing the frequency, starting from zero, the motor moves faster and faster until about 10 Hz, after which around 20 Hz it starts slowing down and then stopping.

The motor makes a sound like it's trying to go faster and faster, but it actually seems to get much weaker after about 15 Hz. The current similarly increases and it looks like it hits around 2 A when the motor is doing like 10 Hz and it goes up to like 4.5 A when I increase the motor up to something like 30 to 40 Hz.

From my very basic understanding, it seems like the VFD would want 60 Hz and would operate the best at that frequency, but it very clearly prefers something like 10 Hz. Also, when it's operating at maximum speed for me it still seems to be going very slow and not as strong or fast as many other of these machines that I've seen people make.

Does anyone know why a three phase motor would behave this way? Is it just that the motor is weak? Do I have something connected Wrong? Is the VFD malfunctioning?

Is everything actually good? Maybe I just need a different worm drive gear thing?

The parts were all new when I got them.

I have connected the three phases of the motor in accordance with its diagram about how to connect a low voltage version, which I'm guessing I should be using since I'm doing 240 instead of 460.

Maybe I should try connecting it up in the high voltage configuration.

That's the only thing left I can think to do in my troubleshooting. Maybe there's a setting in the VFD somehow to alter its behavior. I'm a noob when it comes to VFDs and big AC motors.

[Here's a link to the people who sold me the VFD that I hooked up to my machine.](https://cit-sci.com/v4-extrusion-pro-wiki/)

[The VFD manual is here.](https://www.nvcnc.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/HuanYang-VFD-Manual.pdf)

I tested the three motor wires and they all show about 5.5 amps when at 10hz
[image: amps measured by multimeter]

Comment: A datasheet for your VFD and a schematic showing how you have everything wired up would be helpful.

Comment: What is a "plastic-style plastic extruder"?

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as a "three phase DC induction motor". There is no such thing as multiphase DC, and induction motors are *only* ever AC motors, you physically can't make one that's DC.

Comment: Sorry, yeah it is very much not a DC motor, typed that wrong, thanks @hearth

Comment: updated the description with links  to the VFD manual and schematics and pics @evildemonic

Comment: @Hearth+  --> https://bazar.preciousplastic.com/machines/extruder-pro/

Comment: _”I'm not sure exactly what the single knob is doing”_ This would be where I would recommend you to stop what you are doing and read the manual before you break something. Most VFDs are set up to vary frequency with the knob and the current limit in some sun-menu, but check how yours is made.

Comment: Is your motor wired for Y or delta? Most VFDs require you to wire for delta, but check the VFD manual to be sure.

Comment: Can you verify that the motor current and phase-to-phase voltages are balanced as the speed is increased? Use an external clamp-on current meter and a good true-RMS multimeter. Also, does this happen with the motor unloaded? It could be that the extruder causes a heavier load at higher speeds.

Comment: @winny I have no idea. I tried looking through the manual https://www.nvcnc.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/HuanYang-VFD-Manual.pdf  about anything about Y or delta config, but couldn't find anything, and im not sure what that is off hand

Comment: @PStechPaul sorry it's taken a while at the lab, but finally got it running and tested it. it does seem that all three wires are balanced, they all show about 5.5 amps when at 10hz

Comment: There is a wire obscuring some important info on the nameplate, particularly number of poles and rated speed. The info on your linked website says optimal motor speed is 160-300 RPM, which would correspond to a 10-12 pole motor. Such a motor would have about 10 times the torque as a 2 pole 3600 RPM motor. Lowering speed down to 300 RPM with a VFD will result in low torque and heating. If the motor suddenly speeds up and draws less current, it could be that the extruder starts cavitating like a pump running too fast.

Comment: Ah maybe that's the whole problem. It says the motor is 3450 rpm, which like you said would be 10 times weaker, which feels a bit like what I'm experiencing

Comment: Ahh actually @PStechPaul the motor is 3450rpm (because it seems most electric motors like this are 3450 or 1800rpm) and it goes to the gear reducer (20:1) so it should be spinning like 170rpm at full speed. So i guess that isn't the problem

Comment: I just ran some tests to show video of the problem. First video shows what i have been describing https://youtu.be/c5Jgc7AHaCQ

Comment: There must be some sort of reduction gearing in that extruder. What happens if you clean it out and run it dry?

Comment: Cleaned and running dry it totally exhibits the same behavior. Like it will stall out even when not pushing anything if i try to increase the speed.

Comment: I did run a test with giving it straight 3phase power and it ran awesome and powerful (yet got very hot!) So i think this proves there's something wrong with the VFD https://youtu.be/aICXMTq4jjA @PStechPaul

Comment: Also the blue thing the motor is mounted on is a gear reducer @PStechPaul :) 20:1 worm gear